# Condition on window-functions (SQL)

Tags: sql-server, window-functions

I have a table which I obtain after joining a few tables together, it looks like this:

```
SELECT TOP(200)
A.Value as value,readDate,symbol,description,VIN
FROM Table1 as V
JOIN Table2 ON Table2.VX_Id=V.VX_Id
JOIN Table3 ON Table3.FX_Id =Table2.FX_Id
JOIN Table4 on Table3.FX_Id=Table4.FX_Id
JOIN Table5 as A on A.RX_Id=Table4.RX_Id
WHERE symbol='SV'
ORDER BY VIN,readDate


value   readDate                symbol   description      VIN  
------   ---------------------   -----    ----------      ------               
105     2013-02-05 15:17:25.000     SV     text1          C92320
120     2013-02-05 15:25:25.000     SV     text2          C92320
234     2013-01-22 06:17:55.000     SV     text3          F45910   
240     2013-01-23 07:20:55.000     SV     text4          F45910
246     2013-01-23 09:20:55.000     SV     text5          F45910
1500    2015-10-24 12:48:38.000     SV     text6          J20920   
337     2014-01-24 11:58:38.000     SV     text7          P20824
```

I want to calculate the difference for the next value and previous value (a new column with this difference):

```
value    difference      readDate                symbol   description      VIN  
------    ----           ---------------------   -----    ----------      ------               
105       NULL          2013-02-05 15:17:25.000     SV     text1          C92320
120       15            2013-02-05 15:25:25.000     SV     text2          C92320
234       114           2013-01-22 06:17:55.000     SV     text3          F45910   
240       6             2013-01-23 07:20:55.000     SV     text4          F45910
246       6             2013-01-23 09:20:55.000     SV     text5          F45910
1500      1254          2015-10-24 12:48:38.000     SV     text6          J20920   
337       -1163         2014-01-24 11:58:38.000     SV     text7          P20824
```

I can get this table by writing:

```
SELECT TOP(200)
A.Value as value,A.Value-LAG(A.Value, 1) OVER (ORDER BY VIN,readDate) as 
difference,readDate,symbol,description,VIN
FROM Table1 as V
JOIN Table2 ON Table2.VX_Id=V.VX_Id
JOIN Table3 ON Table3.FX_Id =Table2.FX_Id
JOIN Table4 on Table3.FX_Id=Table4.FX_Id
JOIN Table5 as A on A.RX_Id=Table4.RX_Id
WHERE symbol='SV'
```

I'm only interested in the difference which are positive and comes from the same VIN number, so I would not be interested in 114 (as C92320->F45910) or 1254 (as F45910->J20920) . So the table I would like to have would look like:

```
value    difference      readDate                symbol   description      VIN  
------    ----           ---------------------   -----    ----------      ------               
105       NULL          2013-02-05 15:17:25.000     SV     text1          C92320
120       15            2013-02-05 15:25:25.000     SV     text2          C92320
234       NULL          2013-01-22 06:17:55.000     SV     text3          F45910   
240       6             2013-01-23 07:20:55.000     SV     text4          F45910
246       6             2013-01-23 09:20:55.000     SV     text5          F45910
1500      NULL          2015-10-24 12:48:38.000     SV     text6          J20920   
337       NULL         2014-01-24 11:58:38.000      SV     text7          P20824
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You'll need to `PARTITION` your `LAG`, then it seems you just need a  `CASE` expression.

Comment: @Larnu I'm new to SQL, would appreciate if you could explain more in depth..

Comment: [LAG (Transact-SQL) - Examples: B. Compare values within partitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#b-compare-values-within-partitions) and [CASE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @Larnu Okay! I added PARTITION BY VIN before the ORDER BY, was this correct?

Comment: That's where the documentation says it goes.

Comment: How about the case expression that you mentioned, how do I add that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Larnu pointed out you need `PARTITION BY` and a `CASE` expression to check for negative numbers.

Try this:

```
-- To check for negative numbers we need another select in order to be able to use the result calculated by LAG
SELECT TOP(200) [value], ( CASE WHEN difference < 0 THEN NULL ELSE difference END ) AS difference, readDate, symbol, description, VIN
FROM
    ( SELECT 
    -- Added PARTITION BY
    A.Value as value,A.Value-LAG(A.Value, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY VIN ORDER BY readDate) as 
    difference, readDate, symbol, description, VIN
    FROM Table1 as V
    JOIN Table2 ON Table2.VX_Id=V.VX_Id
    JOIN Table3 ON Table3.FX_Id =Table2.FX_Id
    JOIN Table4 on Table3.FX_Id=Table4.FX_Id
    JOIN Table5 as A on A.RX_Id=Table4.RX_Id
    WHERE symbol='SV' ) AS MainQuery
-- Optionally you can exclude records where difference is 0 or less
WHERE difference > 0
ORDER BY VIN,readDate
```

### Answer to bonus question

To remove duplicate VINs you can try something along those lines:

```
SELECT *
FROM(
    -- To check for negative numbers we need another select in order to be able to use the result calculated by LAG
    SELECT TOP(200) [value], ( CASE WHEN difference < 0 THEN NULL ELSE difference END ) AS difference,
        -- Order differences per VIN in descending order. Note: 1 - is the largest difference; numbering will restart from 1 for each VIN
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY VIN ORDER BY difference DESC ) AS DifferenceRank,
        readDate, symbol, description, VIN
    FROM
        ( SELECT 
        -- Added PARTITION BY
        A.Value as value,A.Value-LAG(A.Value, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY VIN ORDER BY readDate) as 
        difference, readDate, symbol, description, VIN
        FROM Table1 as V
        JOIN Table2 ON Table2.VX_Id=V.VX_Id
        JOIN Table3 ON Table3.FX_Id =Table2.FX_Id
        JOIN Table4 on Table3.FX_Id=Table4.FX_Id
        JOIN Table5 as A on A.RX_Id=Table4.RX_Id
        WHERE symbol='SV' ) AS MainQuery
    -- Optionally you can exclude records where difference is 0 or less
    WHERE difference > 0
    ORDER BY VIN, readDate ) AS DifferenceFilter
-- We only want the biggest difference
WHERE DifferenceRank = 1
```

Comment: Thank you! Another question: After getting this table, how do I select only those rows who have a difference greater then a certain threshold?

Comment: Replace `< 0` with the threshold you are looking for.

Comment: Yes! But how do I filter away all the rows with NULL?

Comment: I want to throw away all the rows that contains a NULL in diff, and just keep the rows who are larger than the threshold. So after I replace <0 with my threshold, I get the rows I'm interested in and also rows with NULL, I want to filter away all those rows with NULL and just keep the rest.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Just use a `WHERE` condition.

Comment: Thank you very much, once again! My last question: Is there a way to only get one row for every unique VIN, meaning that if I have a diff value of 200 for VIN X123 and also the value 1500 for the same VIN X123, I keep only one of those records (perhaps the largest).

Comment: You would need to rank your differences e.g. `ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY VIN ORDER BY difference DESC ) AS DifferenceRank `. This is done in a similar fashion to your `LAG`, where the window function would appear where in the current outermost `SELECT` and then you add another `SELECT` on top.

Comment: Updated my answer, for the last time :)

Comment: I understand what you write, but as a beginner I'm not 100% sure on how to implement these changes. Would you mind sharing the complete query with the changes?

Comment: As stated before I have updated my answer.